# Disable autocorrect UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, autocorrect

Does anyone know how to disable autocorrect programming in uitextview? I have the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
- (void)_setUpTextView {
    self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    self.textView.accessibilityLabel = @"CommentTextView";
    self.textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.textView setFont:[[AppearanceManager sharedManager] brightenFontWithSize:26.0f]];
    [self.textView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
    self.textView.delegate = self;
    self.textView.autocorrectionType = FALSE; // or use  UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo
    self.textView.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    [self addSubview:self.textView];
}
```

Comment: `FALSE` is not an `autocorrectionType`. Why did you comment out `UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo`?

Comment: that would be my error. Thank you! I was using code clips from someone else's code and that was very stupid of me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whoa there buddy, you commented out your own answer. Make this change:

```
self.textView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

And you should be good to go. `autoCorrectionType` does not take a boolean as an argument.